# Nginx request for two or more nodes in Kubernetes

Tags: kubernetes

I'm trying to understand some concepts behind kubernetes, so i have the following:

1. A kubernetes cluster with 2 nodes
2. A deployment of nginx with 2 replicas, so i have 2 POD's.
3. A service exposing nginx on port 32134, so i can access each node with:

   http://node01:32134 or http://node02:32134

So, let's go to my doubts:

1. Doing a `kubectl describe pod nginx-001` i got this pod running under **node01**. Doing the same command to pod nginx-002 i got this pod running under **node01** also. So, if my pods are running under only one node how i can get HTTP 200 in both URL (node01 and node02) ? Node02 should not respond because don't have any nginx running, right ?
2. Looking at `kubctl logs -f nginx-001` i got all access requests log. The strange thing is: Don't matter if i hit `http://node01` or `http://node02` i always get logs in nginx-001 POD, the other pod (nginx-002) never get requests in log. Seems like **ks8** is redirecting all requests to nginx-001 always and forget the other pod.

**Important note**
I'm using Digital Ocean Kubernetes services

Answer (score 6, accepted):

1) Thats where kube-proxy steps in. Kube-proxy is responsible to route your requests to the pods, irrespective of where the pod is deployed. You could have a 50 node cluster. You could have a 10 replica nginx deployed will all replicas deployed on only 1 node and it will be kube-proxy's job to route the requests to the service.

2) That basically depends on how much load you're encountering. You probably are the only one hitting the nginx service. So it persists on sending requests to one pod. Kubernetes service enables load balancing across a set of server pods, allowing client pods to operate independently and durably.

Comment: About (1) answer, if all POD's are within node-01 i don't need node-02 ? About (2) if ks8 make your own load balance i don't need a external load balance ?

Comment: 1) It al depends on how you schedule your pods. And what is the scheduling mechanism. For max durability and fault tolerance, you could deploy a daemon set meaning all your nodes will have 1 pod of nginx running. 2) No. You could use the standard set of services offered to load balance. To get deeper into routing, you could look into istio. But an external load balancer to route traffic internal to the k8s cluster is not needed.

Comment: Sorry but i don't understand why i need say to k8s use all my nodes. I imagine the following: If i have 5 nodes and 10 pods, k8s should distribute this pods between nodes to better performance and optimization of resources. If one node fail the other have same pod running and client don't feel anything

Comment: Forget, i got the problem. I just drop my deployment and recreat and now each pod is inside each node. I created new node after deployment running, show i should destroy and recreate.